# How to perform assignment destructuring using the walrus operator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, destructuring, python-3.8

I can do an assignment destructuring as:

```
a, b = s.split(' ', 1)
```

for a string `s` which has more than one word.

How can we do the same in, say an **`if`** or **`elif`**, with the latest assignment expression introduced in Python 3.8 (is it possible to have multiple targets) ?

I tried:

```
if some_thing:
    # some code.
elif (a, b := s.split(' ', 1)) and some_func(a) and some_func(b):
    # some code probably using a and b as well.
```

I get following error:

```
elif (a, b := s.split(' ', 1)) and some_func(a) and some_func(b):
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

The reason I want this is because I don't want to split my string unnecessarily if my first condition is satisfied.

Comment: I just tried doing 'elif ((a,b) := ..... and got SyntaxError: cannot use named assignment with tuple
So I don't think it's possible to do what you want. saying a, b = s.split() is implicitly working with tuples.

Answer (score 10):

If you try it with parentheses around your assigned-to tuple, the error message is way clearer and tells you something about the problem:

```
if ((a, b) := s.split(' ', 1)):
  ...
```

This will result in a `SyntaxError: cannot use assignment expressions with tuple`.  And that's the whole point:  Currently the walrus operator doesn't allow unpacking assignment.  I also have no information about whether this is planned for the future or not.  (Maybe there is even a logical reason I couldn't figure out why this isn't possible at all.)  Given that they *stripped* the unpacking feature in parameter lists of functions (when moving from Python2 to Python3), I wouldn't expect it.

So all you can do here is the workaround of assigning to a single variable and indexing this later on.

Comment: Open question at https://bugs.python.org/issue43143 (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59567172/multiple-assignments-via-walrus-operator)

Answer (score 4):

See comment on question re assigning to a tuple. I'm by no means an expert though. Posting the below because it works and I think it may be good enough for you? Basically, save the tuple to one variable, which works, and then you can index it

```
if some_thing:
    # some code.
elif (split := s.split(' ', 1)):
    if some_func(split[0]) and some_func(split[1]):
        # some code probably using a and b as well.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know it works for a normal assignment; was keen on how the destructuring can be done. But I guess you're right that we can't do it in the way I did. Btw you could couple both `elif` and the `if` below together with an `and`.