# Multiple assignments via walrus := operator?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, python-3.8

I've attempted to make multiple assignments with the walrus operator, and seen questions on StackOverflow such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59226071/how-to-perform-assignment-destructuring-using-the-walrus-operator-in-python) which also fail to assign multiple variables using a walrus operator, and am just wondering what a successful multiple assignment would look like, or whether it is not possible.

The purpose of doing so is to add support for detecting all assigned variable names in my library [mvdef](https://github.com/lmmx/mvdef) (specifically, within the [`find_assigned_args`](https://github.com/lmmx/mvdef/blob/master/mvdef/src/ast_util.py) function in the `mvdef.src.ast_util` module).

From running `ast.parse` I can see that the `:=` operator produces an `ast.NamedExpr` node, and this has a `.target` attribute which is an `ast.Name` object, from which I can obtain the assigned name from the object's `.id` attribute.

If I had to guess, I'd presume that if it were to be at all possible, the `.target` attribute would be a list of `ast.Name` objects instead of a single `ast.Name` object, however the fact that I can't seem to get an example of this makes me wonder whether it is impossible, at least for the time being (in which case I can simplify my code and not just guess at what an implementation should be).

If anyone knows which specific part of the Python source to look at to tell me if this is possible or not, that'd be helpful, thanks!

P.S. - from looking at the test cases in `Lib/test/test_parser.py` provided in the [initial commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/8f59ee01be3d83d5513a9a3f654a237d77d80d9a) ([via](https://bugs.python.org/issue35224)), there don't seem to be examples of multiple assignments with the walrus operator, so I'm going to assume for now it's not possible (but please chime in if I'm wrong!)

```py
def test_named_expressions(self):
    self.check_suite("(a := 1)")
    self.check_suite("(a := a)")
    self.check_suite("if (match := pattern.search(data)) is None: pass")
    self.check_suite("[y := f(x), y**2, y**3]")
    self.check_suite("filtered_data = [y for x in data if (y := f(x)) is None]")
    self.check_suite("(y := f(x))")
    self.check_suite("y0 = (y1 := f(x))")
    self.check_suite("foo(x=(y := f(x)))")
    self.check_suite("def foo(answer=(p := 42)): pass")
    self.check_suite("def foo(answer: (p := 42) = 5): pass")
    self.check_suite("lambda: (x := 1)")
    self.check_suite("(x := lambda: 1)")
    self.check_suite("(x := lambda: (y := 1))")  # not in PEP
    self.check_suite("lambda line: (m := re.match(pattern, line)) and m.group(1)")
    self.check_suite("x = (y := 0)")
    self.check_suite("(z:=(y:=(x:=0)))")
    self.check_suite("(info := (name, phone, *rest))")
    self.check_suite("(x:=1,2)")
    self.check_suite("(total := total + tax)")
    self.check_suite("len(lines := f.readlines())")
    self.check_suite("foo(x := 3, cat='vector')")
    self.check_suite("foo(cat=(category := 'vector'))")
    self.check_suite("if any(len(longline := l) >= 100 for l in lines): print(longline)")
    self.check_suite(
        "if env_base := os.environ.get('PYTHONUSERBASE', None): return env_base"
    )
    self.check_suite(
        "if self._is_special and (ans := self._check_nans(context=context)): return ans"
    )
    self.check_suite("foo(b := 2, a=1)")
    self.check_suite("foo(b := 2, a=1)")
    self.check_suite("foo((b := 2), a=1)")
    self.check_suite("foo(c=(b := 2), a=1)")
```

Comment: The  left-hand argument to `:=` must be an identifier, nothing else. If by "multiple assignment" you mean tuple unpacking (`a, b = ...`), it simply isn't allowed.

Comment: From [PEP-572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#id9): "This is of the form NAME := expr where expr is any valid Python expression other than an unparenthesized tuple, and **NAME is an identifier**."

Comment: Also note within the spec, that [multiple targets are not directory supported](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#id14). I know this isn't the same as destructuring, but it goes along with @chepner 's comments.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the comments! If someone wants to write an answer I'm happy to accept and close. I did mean "unpacking" yes

Comment: There is an [open issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue43143) about allowing tuple unpacking on the left-hand side of the “walrus” operator.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Iterable packing and unpacking is one difference between `=` and `:=`, with only the former supporting them. As found in [PEP-572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#differences-between-assignment-expressions-and-assignment-statements):

```py
# Equivalent needs extra parentheses
loc = x, y  # Use (loc := (x, y))
info = name, phone, *rest  # Use (info := (name, phone, *rest))

# No equivalent
px, py, pz = position
name, phone, email, *other_info = contact
```

Comment: Does anyone know the reasoning? It would be more intuitive if it worked the same and arguably the grammar would be simpler, no? Just reuse the rule with different precedence.

Comment: @wihlke The PEP seems to imply that if one requires "advanced assignment features" one should use an assignment statement instead of an expression. This is in line with the [PEP 20](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/) principle "explicit is better than Implicit". Particularly in a conditional like `if x, y := ...` the result of the condition is unclear (if it preserved the value of the RHS tuple, the condition would always evaluate to True).

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is that you can not do multiple assignment with walrus -- `:=` but in my view, this is not a significant shortcoming as there is a way around it.

We can always wrap the function that returns multiple values with a function that takes the rest of return values as an input argument.

Consider the following example:

```
if not (userNameCapture := icm.subProc_bashOut(
        f"""grep Username: {plonePasswdFile} | cut -d ":" -f 2""",
        outcome=cmndOutcome,)): return icm.EH_badOutcome(cmndOutcome)
```

Here I get stdout as main return value and I get stderr in `outcome`.

All is good and we end up with benefits of both walrus and multiple assignment.

Comment: I see a return but no definition, how is this supposed to work?